# Select query with join where response fields include table name?

Tags: knex.js

```
await pg
    .select()
    .table("table_a")
    .join("table_b", { "table_a.table_b_id": "table_b.id" })
    .limit(10);
```

Where the results are named like 
[{"table_a.id": "...", ... "table_b.id"}]

With the table name somehow in the hash key for result row.  Is there built in way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you need to give all selected column names manually

```
await pg
    .select(
      'table_a.col1 as tbla_col1', 
      'table_a.col2 as tbla_col2', 
      'table_b.col1 as tblb_col1', 
      ... more columns ...
    )
    .table("table_a")
    .join("table_b", "table_a.table_b_id", "table_b.id")
    .limit(10);
```